# Uncaught Reference Error Using Discord.JS in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, discord.js

I am trying to use the Discord.js package in my Angular app. I created a DiscordBotService that is in my app.component.ts constructor just to try to test if it is working. I am getting an Uncaught Reference Error

```
Client.js:37 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at new Client (Client.js:37)
    at Module../src/app/discord/discord-bot.service.ts (discord-bot.service.ts:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app.component.ts (app.component.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.module.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:13)
```

discord-bot.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import * as Discord from "discord.js";

const client = new Discord.Client();

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export default class DiscordBotService {
  constructor() {
    console.log(client);
  }
}
```

To my package.json, I added

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run server-side code in the browser? Angular is client-side, in-browser code; discord bots are executed with nodeJS (where `process` is definitely defined, as opposed to inside a browser)

Comment: @ChrisG My stack is Angular and Django, where would I put the discord bot?

Comment: You can use [python](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot) instead, or you install node on your server and keep using discord.js

Comment: Appreciate the help! I am setting this up now. I am assuming this means I am creating a separate node directory which is basically acting as an API I would call from Django? i.e. if I want to add a user to a server on Discord using DiscordJS, I would have a django API like https://url/django_path/addToServer/:id which would call a node API like https://url/node_path/addToServer/:id which would then call the DiscordJS API discordJS.addToServer(). * I would be calling Django API first to handle authentication.